# Managment forms data is missing or has been tampered with validation forms

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have searched everywhere but i could not get it resolved. I have a formset (table in the bottom) in my page. The main form and the formset need to be saved when i press a save button using ajax. The POST request is sent but there is error.

**ERROR "POST /new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59**

**ValidationError: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']**

**Views.py**

```
def master_detail_new(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    author = TmpPlInvoice()
    author_form = TmpForm(instance=author)
    BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TmpPlInvoice, TmpPlInvoicedet,
                                        exclude=('emp_id', 'voucher', 'lineitem', 'id',),
                                        form=TmpFormDetForm, )
    formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
    return render(request, 'main.html',
                  {'form': author_form, 'formset': formset, 'formtotal': totalform, 'postform': postform},
                  )

    elif request.method == 'POST':
    def get_new_voucher_id():
        temp_vid = TmpPlInvoice.objects.order_by().values_list("voucher_id", flat=True).distinct()
        if not temp_vid:
            voucher_id = str(1).zfill(4)
        else:
            voucher_id = str(int(max(temp_vid)) + 1).zfill(4)
        return voucher_id

    author_form = TmpForm()
    author = TmpPlInvoice()
    BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TmpPlInvoice, TmpPlInvoicedet, exclude=('emp_id', 'voucher', 'lineitem', 'id',),
                                        form=TmpFormDetForm, extra=2)
    formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
    voucher_id = get_new_voucher_id()
    author = TmpForm(request.POST)
    if author.is_valid():
        created_author = author.save(commit=False)
        created_author.voucher_id = voucher_id
        created_author.save()

        formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=created_author)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="x_content">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
     <table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table   bulk_action form"
   id="formset" style="background-color:#d0ffff;">
       <thead style="background-color:#9df0e0;;color: #73879C">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% endif %}
```

**Javascript to send the data**

```
$("#save").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
        url:'/new/',
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
   });

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    $('#myForm').html(data);
   }
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.
[Multiple formsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SyU0.png)

**EDIT**
i am not changing the number of formsets. My CSRF is working fine. Also, i am getting the same issue without ajax.

```
 <input id="id_tmpplinvoicedet_set-TOTAL_FORMS" name="tmpplinvoicedet_set-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3" />
 <input id="id_tmpplinvoicedet_set-INITIAL_FORMS" name="tmpplinvoicedet_set-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" />
 <input id="id_tmpplinvoicedet_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="tmpplinvoicedet_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" />
 <input id="id_tmpplinvoicedet_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="tmpplinvoicedet_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" />
```

Comment: Are you sure the csrf token you're passing in is correct?

Comment: Do you use javascript to change the number of forms in the formset?

Comment: Does it work if you submit the form without ajax? It looks as if your `data` contains the csrf token but nothing else.

Comment: @Alasdair Data is going through the searchSuccess function. Output Data for Author is {'cust': None, 'voucher_date': None, 'particulars': u'', 'pos_code': None, 'voucher_id': u'', 'acct': None}

Comment: @schwobaseggl how do i confirm where the form number is changing. I am not adding any using javascript.

Comment: @Bono yes it is passing fine.

Comment: @ZarghunaNaseem It would have to be client-side, most likely javascript. Otherwise this error makes little sense other then the afforementioned csrf issue.

Comment: The `success` callback runs after you get a successful response. It isn't used to submit data.

Comment: @Alasdair, This might sound like a dumb question. How can i click the save button and save the data in db but stay on the same page? I could not do that thats why i moved to ajax.

Comment: Ajax is the way to send the request while staying on the same page. However, I always recommend getting the view to work without Javascript first, otherwise it's difficult to debug many parts at once.

Answer (score 2):

This exact error is raised by the formset if the number of forms has changed after having been sent to the browser. The formset uses the hidden input field by the name of `form-TOTAL_FORMS` in the `management_form` to keep track of that number. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform):

> It is used to keep track of how many form instances are being displayed. If you are adding new forms via JavaScript, you should increment the count fields in this form as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I change the TOTAL_FORMS for each form. Note* I pass in a single form as all HTML and the regex the ID when dynamically adding a form to the page.

One the add form button i call:

```
addForm: function () {
    this.count++
    let form_count = this.count
    form_count++

    let formID = 'id_form-' + this.count

    incremented_form = this.vue_form.replace(/form-\d/g, 'form-' + this.count)
    this.formList.push(incremented_form)
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        let total_forms = document.getElementsByName('form-TOTAL_FORMS').forEach
        (function (ele, idx) {
            ele.value = form_count
            })
        })
},
```

This will all 1 to all TOTAL_FORMS. from my very little experience, django looks at the last form to see if that one has the number of forms submitted correct. So you may not have to update a